# How do you "join" the results of two unix commands in a bash script?

Tags: bash

The following returns a list of all the file descriptors associated with sockets in an application:

```
ls -haltr /proc/$PID/fd/  | cut -f3 -d":" | cut -f2 -d"[" | cut -f1 -d"]"  | grep '^[0-9][0-9]*$'  | sort -h
```

The file descriptor, is the same number as found using the `-e` flag in netstat, it is the last column:

```
netstat -ante
tcp    0  0 1.9.146.125:41460  192.28.1.48:443   ESTABLISHED 0   83999      
tcp    0  0 1.9.146.125:59270  192.28.7.28:443   ESTABLISHED 0   58975      
tcp    0  0 1.9.146.125:34948  192.28.14.8:443   ESTABLISHED 0   67916
```

How do I join the two together, so I can just see the lines that match the file descriptors?

Comment: What's the underlying problem? Getting address of open connections for a given PID?

Comment: Fundamentally I am wanting to work out how to join the output of two bash commands based upon a column in the results. But yes, I am trying to work out what this application (pid) is getting stuck connected to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked out a method using trial and error. I bet there is a better way to do it though:

```
arr=(`ls -haltr /proc/2293/fd/  | cut -f3 -d":" | sort -u | \
  cut -f2 -d"[" | cut -f1 -d"]"  | grep '^[0-9][0-9]*$'  | sort -h`); \
  pat=$(echo ${arr[@]}|tr " " "|"); netstat -ante | grep -Ew "($pat)"
```

Comment: There is the `join` command that could be used, too.  The semicolon and backslash seem to be superfluous — one-liner is a pejorative term, not a term of praise.

Comment: I was not aware of the Join command, thanks. I'll look it up; The backslash was just to make it readable on stack overflow; I have no emotional association (good or bad) with the term one–liner.